# Merge 2 SQL queries.

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Im coding (or should I say recoding) a plugin for Wordpress.

I have this query to print year, month and total distance pr month using the meta.key: '_rl_distance_value':

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( wp_posts.post_date, '%Y' ) AS Runyear, MONTH( wp_posts.post_date ) AS Runmonth, SUM( wp_postmeta.meta_value ) AS Distance
FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON ( wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id )
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_rl_distance_value'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id
AND year(wp_posts.post_date)= '2010'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( wp_posts.post_date, '%Y-%m' )
```

It prints something like this:

```
Runyear     Runmonth    Distance    
2010    1   76260
2010    2   88670
2010    3   106490
2010    4   57199
2010    5   66460
2010    6   84480
2010    7   54490
2010    8   45090
2010    9   27140
2010    10  70600
2010    11  51000
```

I also have this query to get total time running each month using the meta.key: '_rl_time_value'

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( wp_posts.post_date, '%Y-%m' ) AS Runyear, MONTH( wp_posts.post_date ) AS Runmonth, ((SUM( time_to_sec( STR_TO_DATE( wp_postmeta.meta_value, '%T' ) ) ) )/3600) AS Runtimetotal
FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON ( wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id )
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_rl_time_value'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND year(wp_posts.post_date)= '2010'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( wp_posts.post_date, '%Y-%m' )
```

It prints something like:

```
Runyear     Runmonth    Runtimetotal    
2010-01     1   7.8928
2010-02     2   9.1667
2010-03     3   10.7083
2010-04     4   5.7497
2010-05     5   6.9561
2010-06     6   8.5594
2010-07     7   5.5767
2010-08     8   4.6139
2010-09     9   2.7233
2010-10     10  7.3953
2010-11     11  4.5858
```

How to merge those 2 queries to have a structure like this

```
Runyear     Runmonth    Distance    Runtimetotal
```

I can not figure out how to do so?

Can you help?

Comment: You could join the results by Runmonth, runyear? select A.*, B.Runtimetotal from A inner join B on A.Runmonth=B.Runmonth and A.Runyear=B.RunYear,

Comment: Can you make an sqlfiddle.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( p.post_date, '%Y-%m' ) AS Runyear,
       MONTH( p.post_date ) AS Runmonth,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_rl_distance_value' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value END) AS Distance,          
       SUM(time_to_sec(STR_TO_DATE(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_rl_time_value' THEN pm.meta_value END, '%T')))/3600 AS Runtimetotal
FROM wp_postmeta pmm INNER JOIN
     wp_posts p
     ON pm.post_id = p.id
WHERE pm.meta_key IN ('_rl_distance_value', '_rl_time_value') AND
      p.post_status = 'publish' AND
      year(p.post_date)= 2010
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(p.post_date, '%Y-%m' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

When I try to run that query in phpmyadmin - I get some errors

Static analysis:

49 errors were found during analysis.

    An alias was previously found. (near "Runmonth" at position 100)
    An alias was expected. (near " " at position 99)
    Unexpected token. (near "Runmonth" at position 100)
    Unexpected token. (near "," at position 108)
    Unrecognized keyword. (near "SUM" at position 118)
    Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 121)
    Unrecognized keyword. (near "CASE" at position 122)...

Sorry if Im a newbie...

Comment: Im no able to edit, 

There are a missing "," after Runyear at the first line. 

But that fixed I still get an error.

`SQL query: Documentation
....
MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'pm.meta_key' in 'field list'`

Can you see anything else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use left and right join and union sudo query in below

```
select t1.*,t2.Runtimetotal from your_1stQuery_output as t1
left join your_2ndQuery_output as t2
on t1.Runyear=t2.Runyear and t1.Runmonth=t2.Runmonth
union
select t2.*,t1.Distance from your_1stQuery_output as t1
right join your_2ndQuery_output as t2
on t1.Runyear=t2.Runyear and t1.Runmonth=t2.Runmonth
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( wp_posts.post_date, '%Y-%m' ) AS Runyear, MONTH( wp_posts.post_date ) AS Runmonth, 
((SUM( case when (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_rl_time_value' then time_to_sec( STR_TO_DATE( wp_postmeta.meta_value, '%T' ) ) ) else 0 end )/3600) AS Runtimetotal, SUM( case when p_postmeta.meta_key = '_rl_distance_value' then wp_postmeta.meta_value else 0) AS Distance
FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON ( wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id )
WHERE (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_rl_time_value' ||wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_rl_distance_value')
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'

AND year(wp_posts.post_date)= '2010'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( wp_posts.post_date, '%Y-%m' )
```

Explanation: If the key is time_value for the runtime, you add the time, and for the distance you add 0. That means the result will not change. Same for the distance_value.

Alternatively, you can:

```
select A.*, B.Runtimetotal 
from A 
inner join B on A.Runmonth=B.Runmonth and A.Runyear=B.RunYear;
```

where A and B are results of your queries